# QGIS SSL error processing QuickMapServices plugin

Tags: qgis, error, quickmapservices, ssl

When I try to search for a map with the Plug In QMS (QuickMapServices) I get this answer.

`Error of processing! SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host=qms.nextgis.com,port=443):Max entries exceeded with url: /api/v1/geoservices?search=google(Caused by SSL Error(SSLError(1, A failure in the SSL library occurred (_ssl.c:1129))))`

I already reinstalled the plugin and also installed the new QGIS version.

Any ideas?

Comment: contact the maintainers at  https://nextgis.com/contact/

Answer (score 2):

such errors are typically related to connectivity issues on a particular machine:

- problems with SSL certificates (misconfiguration via environment parameters, outdated/invalid certificates etc.)
- incorrect/problematic/unset proxy, firewall, VPN settings
- provider issues or blocking of particular IPs
- overly protective antiviruses

Few things to check:

- qms.nextgis.com opens fine in the regular browser on the same machine
- proxy, if present on company network is correctly set in QGIS settings
- try connecting the same machine via different provider (cellphone?) and see if the problem persists
- VPN, if you have any, try to turn it off

Generally, these are not QMS issues and typically should by dealt with by your company admins.

https://github.com/nextgis/quickmapservices/issues/239#issuecomment-1316599823

Comment: Thanks for those tips! For anyone with company computers employing ZScaler it seems to block these API requests.